# Does the state of local variable created by `let` change during recursive call Scheme?

Tags: scheme

For example,

I want to check if an element is in a list. The algorithm is straightforward, let's do it in C++

```
bool element_of( const std::vector<int>& lst, int elem ) {
    for( int i( 0 ), ie = lst.size(); i < ie; ++i ) 
        if( elem == lst[i] )
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

Since Scheme don't let me use single `if` statement, I can't do something similar to the C++ code above. Then I came up with a temporary variable, namely `result`. `result` will have initial value of `#f`, next I recursively call the function to check the next item in the list i.e. `cdr lst` ... So my question is, does the variable which created with `let` restore its initial value each time it enters a new function call or its value stays the same until the last call?

On the other hand, using `fold`, my solution was,

```
(define (element-of x lst)
  (fold (lambda (elem result)
          (if (eq? elem x) (or result #t) result)) 
        #f
        lst))
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `Let` call creates a new set of variables in the environment that the main body of the `Let` is being evaluted in.  The `Let` syntax is a "syntactic sugar" for a lambda being evaluated with arguments passed to it that have been evaluted.  For instance

```
(let ((a (func object))
      (b (func object2)))
     (cons a b))
```

is the same as writing

```
((lambda (a b) (cons a b)) (func object) (func object2))
```

So you can see that in the `Let` syntax, the arguments are first evaluated, and then the body is evaluated, and the definitions of `a` and `b` are utilized in the local environment scope.  So if you recursively call `Let`, each time you enter the body of the `Let` call, you are evaluating the body in a new environment (because the body is inside a newly defined lambda), and the definition of the arguments defined in the local `Let` scope will be different (they are actually new variables in a nested environment setup by the new lambda, not simply variables that have been mutated or "re-defined" like you would find in a C++ loop).

Another way of saying this is that you're variables will be like the local scope variables in a C++ recursive function ... for each function's stack-frame, the locally scoped variables will have their own definition, and their own memory location ... they are not mutated variables like you might see in a loop that re-uses the same memory variables in the local scope.

Hope this helps,

Jason

Comment: Thank you. So I guess the mechanism of Scheme's local variables is exactly like imperative language.

Comment: Sort of ... Scheme's environment model is a necessity because Scheme is not a "pure" functional language, in that it does allows mutability for variables. Basically all variables are symbols held in an "environment", which is basically a symbol table. The `(define a b)` keyword adds symbol `a` to the local environment (symbol table), and binds it to the evaluated value of `b`.  Calling `define` on `a` again would re-bind `a` to something else, unless you call it in a new environment, in which case it adds a new `a` to the symbol table, masking the availability of the old value.

Comment: For more information on Scheme's environment model, check out these links: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-001-structure-and-interpretation-of-computer-programs-spring-2005/lecture-notes/lecture15webhan.pdf

Comment: And this link: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-001-structure-and-interpretation-of-computer-programs-spring-2005/lecture-notes/lecture15webha2.pdf

Answer (score 1):

`let` always reinitialises variables; it's evident, since you must always provide new binding values. e.g.,

```
(let ((a 42))
  ...)
```

Inside the `...`, `a` starts out as 42, always. It doesn't "retain" values from previous invocations.

---

By the way, I think you meant to write `(or result (equal? elem x))` rather than `(if (eq? elem x) (or result #t) result)`. :-)

`(or result (equal? elem x))` translates to the following C++ code:

```
return result || elem == x;
```

(assuming that the `==` operator has been overloaded to perform what `equal?` does, of course.) The benefit of this is that if `result` is already true, no further comparisons are performed.

Comment: Yeah, you were right. When trying to transfer my C++ idea, I was stuck with that one. Thank you.